# WebClient throw exception The remote server returned an error: (507) Insufficient Storage

Tags: c#, web-crawler, webclient, bots

I develop small program that looping to send request to a website.
For get some information that i need from web page, then store to my database.

It is about 1400 requests.

I run it on both developing machine and Windows Azure VM.

At first, it work well on both machine (first day).
But after i run it next day on Windows Azure VM.
It's throw exception like this.

> Web Exception:  System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an
>   error: (507) Insufficient Storage.    at
>   System.Net.WebClient.OpenRead(Uri address)    at
>   System.Net.WebClient.OpenRead(String address)    at
>   StockChecker.MainWindow.Worker_DoWork(Object Sender,
>   DoWorkEventArgs e)

But on developing machine it's no problem.

What happened with it. Is target website detected as bot?
How to fix this issue.

Here is my code.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

List<tbmProduct> prodList = // Get data from my database;

foreach (var prod in prodList)
{
    string content;
    string link = prod.SupplierUrl;

    try
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client.OpenRead(link)))
        {
            content = reader.ReadToEnd();

            // Do something. Update my database.
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        // write log
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // write log
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have met this issue also, and searched a lot document, but not find the fix way. Seems this issue is caused by server settings, so we can not fix it in code. My solution is when the 507 error happened, save the current point, and waiting some minutes then continue to send http request from the break point.